# JS: two or more object properties with the same name in non-strict mode?

Tags: javascript, theory

Reading David Flanagan's Definitive Guide (6th edition), stumbled on this:

> In strict mode, it is a syntax error for an object literal to define
>   two or more properties by the same name. (In non-strict mode, no error
>   occurs.)

I can't find any examples - is it even possible? I tried

```
var obj = {prop: 'foo', prop: 'bar'};
```

...but of course I end up with only one property (`Object {prop: "bar"}`), in both strict and non-strict modes.

Is this implementation-dependent? The book is a 2011 edition, ECMAScript 5 is in there.

Should I be reading a newer book?

Comment: Huh, that’s strange. It’s definitely one of the strict mode restrictions according to the ES5 spec: https://es5.github.io/#C and https://es5.github.io/#x11.1.5. I’m checking to see if ES6 lifted it now (maybe for computed properties).

Comment: no error occurs means no syntax error. An object can't have multiple properties with the same name.

Comment: @thangngoc89 No syntax error occurs in both modes. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book is right; the ES5 specification states that defining multiple properties with the same name in an object literal is a syntax error.

See [section 11.1.5](https://es5.github.io/#x11.1.5) around here:

> If previous is not undefined then throw a SyntaxError exception if any of the following conditions are true

and the informative [Annex C](https://es5.github.io/#C):

> It is a SyntaxError if strict mode code contains an ObjectLiteral with more than one definition of any data property (11.1.5).

The implementations you’re testing are *also* right, however, as the current ECMAScript specification is ES2015, which drops this restriction! It’s not listed in its [Annex C](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-of-ecmascript) or anywhere else.

If I had to guess, it would be that the reason for this removal was consistency with computed properties, so these literals would always be equivalent:

```
({ a: 1, ['a']: 2 })
({ a: 1, a: 2 })
```

But yep, everybody’s right. \o/

Comment: Yes, IIRC, computed properties were the reason, altough they are a horrible reason imo.

Comment: Thank you - so much good info here I had no clue about. Good thing I asked.

Comment: When using the same name for your properties, the second property will overwrite the first. (ECMAScript 2015)